# What is the best version of Java and NetBeans for a robotics application based on a Beaglebone Black controller running Debian?

Tags: java, beagleboneblack

Most of the application is going to be written in Java, but the low level USB interface for communication with a 3Dconnexion Space Navigator is going to be written  in C. I am looking to be able to remote debug the code or just run the IDE on the  Beaglebone Black. I realize that running the IDE on the  Beaglebone Black may be very slow. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You'll find this question is more at home on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

U can try netbeans 8 with any JDK that is newer than 7.4 (as i remember) when writing the code on ur machine. Setup a remote java platform on netbeans and install  Oracle JDK with Hard Float ABI on ur beagle bone (as u are running debian). There are couple of youtube videos that will show u how to do so, most of them are for Raspberry PI but the idea is the same.